# Slave could not register with the master

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I set up the master and slave with the method described at  https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/#master-setup.

After that I could run tasks on Mesos. When restarting the VM again, the IP/s have changed so the slave could not connect to the master anymore.

[image]

I also tried to set the IP but failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the cluster in a High Availability mode, best way is to have zookeeper installed and let mesos-slaves use zookeeper to find out about the master.
For more details look up:
http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability/

For installing in HA mode:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04

Now, it is very useful to have a static private IP for the masters. That way you're not changing the zk url after every reboot.

Comment: It appears the OP is doing his first steps in Mesos, using a VM -- adding HA adds significant complexity and I would discourage doing this until Mesos and VM network configuration are properly mastered.